# Is there a conjectured dependence on $n$ in van der Waerden's conjecture?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

[Bhargava 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.06507) proves van der Waerden's conjecture about Galois groups of random integer polynomials: over all $x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0 = 0$ with $a_k \in \{-H, \ldots, H\}$, the number of polynomials $E_n(H)$ with Galois group not equal to the full symmetric group $S_n$ is $O(H^{n-1})$.

- First (and this is a very basic question), am I correct that the $O$ here is in terms of $H$ only, so that in detail we have $E_n(H) < c_n H^{n-1}$ for some constants $c_n$ that depend on $n$?
- Second, is there a conjectured growth rate for $c_n$?

From [Bhargava 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.06507) it seems like in the worst case $c_n$ might have a factor related to the number of nonisomorphic groups of order $n$ (possibly with other factors), but presumably most of the count concentrates on fewer of the groups.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two different questions you could ask here.

One is the dependence on $n$ in the conjectured asymptotic best constant, i.e. the $c_n$ such that we have $E_n (H) < c_n H^{n-1} + o(H^{n-1})$ with the little $o$ depending on $n$. This one has a precise answer, because we do not need to worry about all the groups that are proven or expected to occur with frequency $o(H^{n-1})$. So we just need to deal with the reducible polynomials, where it was computed by Chela that we can take

$$ c_n = 2^n (\zeta(n-1) - 1/2) + 2 k_n $$
where $k_n$ is the volume of the region in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ consisting of tuples $x_1,\dots, x_{n-1}$ with $$-1 \leq x_1,\dots, x_{n-1}, \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i \leq 1 .$$

It is straightforward to check that this has growth rate proportional to $2^n$ in $n$.

The other is the dependence on $n$ of the conjectured best constant valid for all $H$. This is a somewhat annoying question because it will depend heavily on small values of $H$. For example, we must take $c_n \geq 3^{n-1}$ to deal with the case where $H$ is $1$ (and the constant coefficient vanishes). It's possible that we can take $c_n \leq 3^n$ - I don't see a reason against it.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  So very roughly we might have something like $E_n(H) = O(2^n H^{n-1}) + O(1)^n o(H^{n-1})$ where all constants are absolute.

Also, to clarify: do you mean "occur with frequency $o(H^{n-1})$"?

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving Yes, that sounds exactly right, and that's what I meant to say.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean $k_n$ as written? Isn't it just an (n-1)-simplex of volume $2^{n-1}/(n-1)!$?

Comment: @liuyao I think it's not quite - if you take the standard $n-1$-simplex, double all coordinates, and then subtract $1$ so they range from $-1$ to $1$, then the sum of the coordinates would range from $-(n-1)$ to $-(n-3)$, not from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: @WillSawin I see, it is an (n-1)-simplex still, and has fairly simple expression for the volume. The base edge isn't 2, but n-1.

Comment: @liuya I disagree - I don't think it's a simplex. When $n$ is even, it has $\binom{n}{ n/2}$ vertices, those being the points where the number of coordinates that are $1$ and $-1$ are $\frac{n}{2}$ and $\frac{n-2}{2}$.

Comment: @WillSawin, I see my confusion: you mean each coordinate, and their sum to be between -1 and 1, a total of 2n inequalities. I thought it was just n inequalities. So it's a truncated simplex, if you will.

Comment: @liuyao Yes, perhaps my notation was not the best!